# Manipulating output c++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I am trying to write a simple grocery shopping app, the input is in a format something like this:

```
Item Name
someid expiryDate manufacturerId cost
```

An example is:

Shampoo
8879 05 04 2015 1010 100.03

I want to format it in such a way that: 
8879 05/04/2015 1000 $100.03 .....etc

How do I achieve this?

My attempt:

I tried using substring and then breaking the input down and then outputting in the required format but the issue i came across was that for example the price can be something like 45.00 then my approach would fail.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Check for `std::istringstream` to extract the sub parts.

Comment: @Matt I don't see any relevance mentioning XML formats here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are reading from the console input you can use cin and istringstream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int id;
    int mm,dd,yy;
    int manufacturerId;
    double price;
    string priceString;
    char character; // used to read '/' and other symbols
    cin >> id >> mm >> character >> dd >> character >> yy >> manufacturerId;
    cin >> priceString;

    istringstream stream( priceString );
    stream >> character >> price;

    return 0;
}
```

Note: A nice approach if is to create your own struct/class for the complex objects (like date for example) to extract info and subclass operator>> for them.

```
struct date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

istream& operator>>(istream& stream,date& d)
{
    char character;
    stream >> d.month >> character >> d.day >> character >> d.year;

    return stream;
}
```

Then you can use

```
date d;
cin >> d
```

to read dates which is much more concise and keeps the code in main simple.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but my question is little different. In the sense my input format is like: 8879 05 04 2015 1010 100.03. I basically want to take this input and then store them in variables like month, date, year, id, price, etc. Probably using a for loop. How do i achieve this?

Comment: Well in the code i have some variables( id, mm, dd, yy, price ) to hold this information and populate them when reading from input stream. If you run the code and paste 8879 05 04 2015 1010 $100.03 in the console you will have the data extracted in those variables.